# How will I check that in SQL whether all the values of one column of all rows are same using Java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I m using the database where i need to check that if that particular column of the table has same values for all the rows, as want to see yes or no... If yes then i'll go for one method other wise for other method.

Comment: What is the DBMS you are using?

Comment: `distinct`, `group by` and check result rows?

Comment: M using mysql dbms using jdbc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a SQL connection provisioned from within your Java code already, it should be as easy as comparing a resultset against 0:

```
Connection con DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:driver:host","myLogin","myPassword");    
Statement statement = con.createStatement();
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT columnName) AS columnDistinctCount FROM tableName;");

int uniqueEntryCount = result.getInt("columnDistinctCount");

if (uniqueEntryCount > 0) {
    methodOne();
else {
    methodTwo();
```

Comment: Thank u so much... It really helped me

Comment: You’re welcome, glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that Java is a red herring here.  The SQL that you want is

```
select count( distinct columnName ) from tableName;
```

which tells you how many different values there are of `columnName`.

Comment: It would be nice to include the group by on columnName like @Thomas Banderas mentioned above.

Comment: @LeeWallen, yes, that's another way to do it.  You could write an answer using your technique if you want to.

Comment: I liked that you included the actual SQL in an answer, and figured it might be nice to reference the comment from above that included the group by.  Your current answer is sufficient for answering the question as it was asked. :)